# Views behave awkwardly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

Consider a part of Backbone.js source code:

```
// List of view options to be merged as properties.
var viewOptions = ['model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events'];

var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
    options || (options = {});
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
    this._ensureElement();
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.delegateEvents();
};
```

I wonder why only 'model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events' are assigned to View instances. I found this annoying. I usually need to send some extra parameters. Is it ok to replace `_.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));` with 
`_.extend(this, options));`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store your extra data in the attributes hash?

If you really want to set additional properties directly on the view you could also pass it in as the attributes option then set it on the view object in the initialize method:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;

        if (this.attributes) {
            _.each(this.attributes, function(val, key) {
                self[key] = val;
            });
        }
    }
});

var view = new MyView({ attributes: { foo: 'bar' } });
```

Comment: Indeed I use a similar code right now. I want to know the reasons behind `var viewOptions = ['model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events'];`

Comment: Ah. Yeah I don't know the reasoning behind the whitelist. Maybe it's to keep the top level view properties uncluttered. Or using the attributes property to store arbitrary data in the view is meant to be consistent with the way models are implemented? 

I guess my inclination is usually just to avoid modifying third-party source code :)